# How to pass in any method as a parameter to determine if it throws an exception

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a method where I can pass in any method call and determine if it does not throw an exception.

```
/// <summary>
/// No exceptions thrown
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public bool NoThrows(Action method)
{
    try
    {
        method();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        throw new AssertException(string.Format("Boom: {0}", exception));
    }
}
```

When I pass in a method that returns void such as `.Click()`

```
foo.NoThrows(officeDropDown.Click());
```

I get `Argument type 'void' is not assignable to System.Action`...is it possible to pass in any method call as an object and determine if it throws any exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an instance of an `Action` to pass to the method, just as you would with any other argument.

C# will convert a lambda or a method group into an Action for you implicitly:

```
foo.NoThrows(() => officeDropDown.Click()); // Lambda
foo.NoThrows(officeDropDown.Click); // Method group
```

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the method, not method result:

```
foo.NoThrows(officeDropDown.Click);
```

Or you can pass a lambda expression:

```
foo.NoThrows(() => officeDropDown.Click());
```